# How to automatically start an Activity on launch if a Foreground Service / Notification is up?

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

Let's say I have the following app components:

- Activity **A1** (Launcher Activity)
- Activity **A2**
- Service **S**

They must behave in the following way:

> - Under normal conditions, **A1** should start both **A2** and **S**.
> - On creation, **S** should change itself to foreground, creating a notification **N**.
> - On creation, **A2** should bind to **S**.
> - When the user selects **N**, **A2** should be started.

I know how to implement this behaviour. What I don't know is how to implement the following:

> - If for some reason the user leaves the application while **S** is still in foreground, **A2** should be started when the application
>     launches (instead of **A1**, which would be the launcher activity).

Any ideas?